# Get selected country from ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Dear Community Member(s)

Following a search online with regards to [Binding country list using cultureinfo in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://www.compilemode.com/2018/02/bind-country-list-using-cultureinfo-in-asp-net-mvc.html)

updating the `Controller` thanks to the following codes did help:

```
        List<string> CountryList = new List<string>() ;
        CultureInfo[] CInfoList = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
        foreach (CultureInfo CInfo in CInfoList)
        {
            RegionInfo R = new RegionInfo(CInfo.LCID);
            if (!(CountryList.Contains(R.EnglishName)))
            {
                CountryList.Add(R.EnglishName);
            }
        }

        CountryList.Sort();
        ViewBag.CountryList = CountryList;
        return View();
```

in conjunction with the following `Tag Helper` from `View`:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("CountryList",new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList), "Select a country", new 
 {@class = "form-control" })
```

However, I wonder how to `Get`/Read the value of a selected country, still via a `Controller's method`. I had in mind defining firstly
in `Model` a `public property` such as:

```
public IEnumerable <SelectListItem> countryList {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

but I am keen on knowing a better way of achieving this via a `Model`.

*N.B:* In `ASP.NET` I used to achieving such request through:

```
string example = testid.SelectedItem.Text;
```

after adding an event to

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="testid" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="test_event" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true"> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Any relevant feedback would highly be appreciated.

*N.B: The ideal solution shall involve defining `CountryList` (e.g. `countrylist`) in `Model` as a public property, so as to be able to retrieve any selected country via a Controller's method.*

Best

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the selected value in controller,you can try to use a form,when the selected item change,pass the selected value to controller,here is a demo:

action:

```
public IActionResult TestCountryList(string CountryList)
        {
            List<string> countryList = new List<string>();
            CultureInfo[] CInfoList = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
            foreach (CultureInfo CInfo in CInfoList)
            {
                RegionInfo R = new RegionInfo(CInfo.LCID);
                if (!(countryList.Contains(R.EnglishName)))
                {
                    countryList.Add(R.EnglishName);
                }
            }

            countryList.Sort();
            ViewBag.CountryList = countryList;
            return View();
        }
```

TestCountryList View:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
        @Html.DropDownList("CountryList", new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList), "Select a country", new
    { @class = "form-control" })
    </form>
    @section scripts
    {
        <script>
            $("#CountryList").change(function () {
                $("#myform").submit();
            })
        </script>
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: since all the fields of my ```form``` are called via their equivalent properties from the ```Model```, I was more looking for a way to define ```CountryList``` in this part too. (e.g. Model). Underlying Reason: my <button type="submit"> does lots of checks on all the form's fields through their ```public properties```.